# No query results for model [App\Product] 36

Tags: php, laravel

when i run it.it prompt out and error [No query results for model [App\Product] 36].

this is the controller code.

```php
public function  wishList(Request $request)
{        
    $products = DB::table('wishlist')->leftjoin('products', 'products.id' , '=', 'wishlist.pro_id')->get();
    return view('wishlist',compact('products'));
}
```

this is the route.

```php
Route::get('addToWishList','UserProfileController@addWishList');
Route::get('/wishlist','UserProfileController@wishList');
Route::get('/removeWishList/{id}', 'UserProfileController@removeWishList');
```

this is the page interface code. the error shoe that the problem is came from here.

```html
<tbody>
@forelse($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{url('/')}}/removeWishList/{{$product->id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="{{url('/assets/images/products')}}/{{\App\Product::findOrFail($product->pro_id)->feature_image}}" alt="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{url('/product',$product->id)}}">
            {{$product->title}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <td>{{$settings[0]->currency_sign}}<span id="price{{$product->id}}">{{\App\Product::Cost($product->id)}}</span></td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form class="addtocart-form">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                @if(Session::has('uniqueid'))
                    <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{Session::get('uniqueid')}}">
                @else
                    <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{str_random(7)}}">
                @endif
                <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{$product->id}}">
                <input type="hidden" id="cost" name="cost" value="{{\App\Product::Cost($product->id)}}">
                <input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
                @if($product->stock != 0 || $product->stock === null )
                    <button type="button" class="addTo-cart to-cart"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i><span>{{$language->add_to_cart}}</span></button>
                @else
                    <button type="button" class="addTo-cart  to-cart" disabled><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>{{$language->out_of_stock}}</button>
                @endif
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: do you want to get all products?

Comment: Did you check whether the database query actually returns any result? Looks like either your database is empty or query is returning empty (possible because of the `left join`)

Comment: And why is there a `leftjoin`? Why aren't you using a model relationship?

Comment: Your `wishList` function, as shown, won't generate this error. Are you sure you're showing us the right code?

Answer (score 0):

That error means a Model was used to find a record or fail basically. It could not find the record by the id provided.

Since Models are not referenced in your Controller I would assume this line from the view has to do with your error:

```
{{ \App\Product::findOrFail($product->pro_id)->feature_image }}
```

If it can't find a `Product` by the id of `$product->pro_id` it will fail and end up with such error message as it will throw an exception.

The only other references to the model are `App\Product::Cost(...)` not sure what that is doing but you are always passing in a product id it seems.